# RESOURCE EXHAUSTED error with Kfold on a facial landmarks data

Tags: data-science-model, ai

i am currently working with helen dataset to predict facial landmarks. Currently running the program on a Geforce 1070. The highest batch size i can give is 230 and i am getting a loss of 3 and accuracy of 40%. i am unable to use KFold cross validation as it gives a RESOURCE EXHAUSTED error. Any suggestions.

Comment: A higher batch size increases the memory footprint. Have you tried lowering it?

Comment: @PascalIv, I have used a batch size of 1,10,32,64 and the min training loss is 2 and validation loss is 3. Unable to reduce it further. I'm open for any suggestions of other datasets I can work on. Thank you.